# Right Triangle Implementation

Tags: swift

Given this struct:

```
struct RightTriangle {

var length: Double
var width: Double

var hypotenuse : Double {
    get {
        return sqrt((self.length * self.length) + (self.width * self.width))
    }
  }
}
```

I can easily create an instance of it:

```
var rightTriangleOne = RightTriangle(length: 3.0, width: 4.0)
```

and obtain the hypotenuse value:

```
rightTriangleOne.hypotenuse //returns 5.0
```

**Now Here's the Problem**

What if I want to **set** the hypotenuse to a specific value, and let the width and length values reflect the changes?

We could create a setter where we reassign the width or length (width in this case) based on the new hypotenuse value:

```
set {
      self.width = sqrt((newValue * newValue) - (length * length))
}
```

Now if we check our values:

```
rightTriangleOne.width // 4.0
rightTriangleOne.length // 3.0
rightTriangleOne.hypotenuse // 5.0
```

everything is good, but now let's try to set the hypotenuse to a new value:

```
rightTriangleOne.hypotenuse = 10.0
```

Cool, let's now check our length and width (the width should modify itself to allow the hypotenuse to be 10, but not mess with the length):

```
rightTriangleOne.width // 9.539392014169456
rightTriangleOne.length // 3.0
```

This is great and all, but there is a problem. The problem is if we set the length or width to anything other than it's current value, the hypotenuse is going to change, and I don't want it to.

**For example**

If I set the hypotenuse to 10, and the width to 4, the length should be set to around 9.16.

Is this implementation possible? I'm trying to do this strictly with computed properties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know swift, but in general, you need a specialized type whose hypotenuse length is constant, or a specialised routine that will change the length or width while maintaining a constant hypotenuse length.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing. I have a colleague that proposed this to me, and I couldn't figure it out by just doing computed properties. With high hopes, I'll keep the question posted. Thanks for the help @phoog

Comment: So, if you set any two properties, the third one will be computed automatically?

Comment: In this case, yes. I'm not sure if this functionality is possible solely using computed properties, what do you think? @vacawama

Comment: I think you need two properties to keep track of the most recently set sides, values to keep track of the current length of each of the sides, and then use those to compute the third.

Comment: Could you leave an answer please, so I can see more explicitly what you're trying to explain? @vacawama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom setters on `width` and `length`:

```
struct RightTriangle: CustomStringConvertible {
    private var _length: Double
    private var _width: Double

    var length: Double {
        get {
            return _length
        }
        set {
            let h = self.hypotenuse
            _length = newValue
            _width = sqrt(h * h - _length * _length)
        }
    }

    var width: Double  {
        get {
            return _width
        }
        set {
            let h = self.hypotenuse
            _width = newValue
            _length = sqrt(h * h - _width * _width)
        }

    }

    var hypotenuse: Double {
        get {
            return sqrt(length * length + width * width)
        }
        set {
            _width = sqrt((newValue * newValue) - (length * length))
        }
    }

    init(length: Double, width: Double) {
        _length = length
        _width = width
    }

    var description: String {
        return "length = \(length), width = \(width), hypotenuse = \(hypotenuse)"
    }
}

var x = RightTriangle(length: 3, width: 4)
x.hypotenuse = 10
x.width = 4

print(x) // length = 9.1651, width = 4.0, hypotenuse = 10.0
```

The ivars `_length` and `_width` are what actually stored the dimensions of the triangle. Their corresponding properties have custom setter to coordinate the change to the other side.

This comes with 2 assumptions:

- If you change the `hypotenuse`, it's `width` that will be changed to match
- It has no error check for impossible triangle dimensions, like negative, or `length = 10, hypotenuse = 5` then `width = nan`

Comment: Decent idea, but you don't need the separate private storage properties — just use `willSet` or `didSet`.